# Intuition for difference in asymptotic distribution

Tags: asymptotics, delta-method

I am looking for some intuition on the following:
Assume a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ for which we know that the following hold:
$$X_n \xrightarrow{p} c \neq 0$$
$$Z_n \equiv \sqrt{n}(X_n - c) \xrightarrow{d} Z= N(0, v)$$
$$g(X_n) \xrightarrow{p} g(c)$$

where $c$ is a real constant.

We have $g(X_n)\cdot Z_n =  \sqrt{n}\Big(g(X_n)X_n - g(X_n)c\Big)$

and applying Slutsky's theorem we obtain

$$\sqrt{n}\Big(g(X_n)X_n - g(X_n)c\Big)\xrightarrow{d} g(c)Z = N\big(0, [g(c)]^2v\big) ]\tag{1}$$

But if we apply the Delta Theorem on $g(X_n)\cdot Z_n$ we have that

$$g(X_n)\cdot X_n \approx g(c)\cdot c + \big[g'(c)\cdot c+g(c)\big]\cdot [X_n-c]$$

which will lead to

$$\sqrt {n}\Big(g(X_n)X_n - g(c)\cdot c\Big)\xrightarrow{d} N\big(0, [g'(c)\cdot c+g(c)\big]^2v\big) \tag{2}$$

that has a different variance.

Certainly, the left-hand-sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not the same. But because $g(c)$ is the probability limit of $g(X_n)$, a wrong "intuition" overcame me, and I conjectured that the asymptotic distributions would be the same, prior to working it out.

An afterimage of this wrong intuition remains, so is there a way to understand the above apart from simply deriving it?

(In case I have made a silly mistake somewhere, pointing it out would also be helpful of course).

**NOTE:** Quantities like $g(X_n)X_n$ can be found in for example binary response models (logit etc), where $f(\hat \beta_k)\cdot \hat \beta_k$ would be the estimated marginal effect of a regressor $k$ on the probability of the response variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the simplest case $g(a)=a$.

You apply Slutsky's theorem to 
$$ \sqrt{n}(X_n^2 - X_nc) = \sqrt{n} X_n(X_n-c) \to_d N(0,c^2\nu). $$
But then you apply Delta theorem to $\sqrt{n}(X_n^2-c^2)$. If you were to apply Slutsky's theorem to it, you would get
$$ \sqrt{n}(X_n^2-c^2) = \sqrt{n}(X_n+c)(X_n-c) \to_d N(0,4c^2\nu). $$
The difference between these two is $\sqrt{n}c(X_n-c)$, which converges to $N(0,c^2\nu)$, not zero. When you replace $X_nc$ with $c^2$, you increase the variance, because the "error" in $X_n$ used to be correlated
with the "error" in the first term.

These two things do indeed have different limits:

```
> n <- 100; m <- 1000;
> x <- rnorm(m, 1, 1/sqrt(n));
> c(sd(sqrt(n)*(x*x-1)), sd(sqrt(n)*(x*x-x)))
[1] 2.018918 1.017808
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks, your penultimate sentence prior to the code (about correlation) seems to capture all the essence, the underlying intuition for the different variance, which is what I was after. The only thing that troubles me is that in the more general case, it appears that the variance could be lower, not higher.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos In the more general case the key thing is the sign of $cg'(c)$ vs the sign of $g(c)$.